# Can I somehow revive unrecognizable (micro) SD cards?

Tags: sd-card

I am unsure as to whether to ask here, or on [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

I have a box full of micro SD cards, which I have used over the years for Raspberry Pis. I was searching through them for one to use, and most seemed to be unrecognized.

I am not even sure how an SD card can go wrong, let alone 6 or 8 from a box of 10. Of course, it is possible that I recognized them as defective, but kept them "just in case".

Should I just through them away, or is there any way to rescue them?

Please note that I am not concerned with their current contents.

Comment: Were they formatted with some arbitrary file system? Are you able re-format them, or can you not get that far?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the contacts and inserting them into something that understands EXT3 etc?

Comment: @spikey_richie They were formatted for Raspberry Pi, so are a mix of Linux file systems and FAT. There is an an image at http://www.simplyembedded.org/archives/filesystems-with-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: @ Mokuba from the titles, none of those "duplicates" are applicable to my question. Obviously, if a moderator recommends them, I have to think that there is something in those questions which is pertinent to me. I read them, and could't find it (I am a mawg of very little brain). Could you please tell me what you found in those questions that could help me (and which I obviously missed)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you can't format those SD cards to reuse on your PC or other devices, I suggest you connect those SD cards via RAM Reader one by one, Then fix them using with Storage management like `EaseUS Partition Master 12.0`.
First `wipe data`, and then `format as FAT32` to use it on any devices.